# facebook like button show error

Tags: asp.net, facebook

On [Like Button Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
I want to get Like Button Code.
The Url to like is "http://tour.suiis.com/TourDetail.aspx?scnbr=88".
When I click facebook like button,it show "You Like Error".
I can't find any solution.
Who can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? the debug tool shows some of your meta tags are incorrect or missing, maybe you should fix those first

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the URL isn't reachable to Facebook. Try Facebook's URL linter to make sure.